# How do I use QueryRenderer with subscriptions in React Relay

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, relay

I've got a component that use a query to render its data:

```
// Example.js
import React from 'react';
import { QueryRenderer, graphql } from 'react-relay';

class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <QueryRenderer
        environment={environment}
        query={graphql`
          query ExampleQuery($pageID: ID!) {
            page(id: $pageID) {
              name
            }
          }
        `}
        variables={{
          pageID: '110798995619330',
        }}
        render={({error, props}) => {
          if (error) {
            return <div>{error.message}</div>;
          } else if (props) {
            return <div>{props.page.name} is great!</div>;
          }
          return <div>Loading</div>;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Let's say now I want to rerender it for every update (i.e., use subscription instead of a query.

How do I replace this query with `subscription ExampleQuery($pageID: ID!)`

```
query={graphql`
          query ExampleQuery($pageID: ID!) {
            page(id: $pageID) {
              name
            }
          }
        `}
```